# Dandelion datatables add extra header row for filters

Tags: java, jsp, taglib, dandelion

I have implemented dandelion datatables v1.1.0 in a project, at this moment I need to add a second header (thead) row to add the [yadcf](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf) filters like this:

[image]

I have tried adding a new feature for add the new header row but the sorting icons are in the header row like the next image:

[image]

This is the code of my dandelion table:

```
<datatables:table id="vendedoresTable" data="${vendedoresInstanceList}" row="vendedor"  filterPlaceholder="header" ext="myAwesomeExtension">
            <datatables:column titleKey="table1.header.name" property="nombre" filterable="true" sortable="true"/>
            <datatables:column title="Email" property="email" filterable="true"/>
        </datatables:table>
```

Anyone can help me how can I implement a second header row with filters like the first image?
Thanks

Comment: You / Dandelion author might find the [following issue on yadcf github](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/297) relevant to you, see also [my last comment](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/297#issuecomment-204762695) on it

Comment: This is a good start, thank you ...

Comment: The problem of dandelion is that it puts the sort icon in the last row header column...

Comment: maybe the [orderCellsTop](https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderCellsTop) is also relevant...